# Manter foco no InputText

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Tenho um formulário com dois InputText, preciso que o foco permaneça sempre no Input e só passe para o seguinte via script, caso o usuário clique fora do Input, o foco precisa permanecer no Input. Estou tentando setar o foco, porém não estou conseguindo. Tentei até no console do Firefox (`document.getElementById("login").focus();`), mas recebo a mensagem undefined. No código a seguir, o resultado esperado seria manter o foco no Input ao clicar em qualquer parte da tela, porém somente o alert está sendo exibido. Alguma dica? Valeu pela ajuda.

HTML

```
login:<br><s:textfield name="login" id="login" required="true" cssStyle="width:287px; height:20px;" onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='#F7F5E9'" onfocus="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'"/>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var txtLogin = document.getElementById("login");

    txtLogin.addEventListener('blur', event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert('Passei aqui!!!')
      txtLogin.focus();
    });

});
```

Comment: Se entendi bem, você pode usar o onChange ao invés do onBlur, incluindo o preventDefault() e/ou stopImmediatePropagation(), mas eu acredito que há um grande risco de você causar um loop infinito para o usuário. Não seria melhor atribuir classes de erro/destaque para o campo e não submeter o formulário se o valor não for corrigido?

Comment: @GustavoAdolfo a ideia é ler um código no primeiro campo, fazer uma chamada ajax, caso tenha sucesso, o foco passa para o segundo campo que irá ler códigos e acumular via ajax também. Uma ideia semelhante a um coletor. Eu sempre inicio pelo básico, tentei manter o foco no campo e não consegui. Você teria alguma dica? Obrigado pela sua resposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiz esse exemplo com jQuery, funciona assim vc tem dois `input` um obrigatório, e outro `desable`, então vc não consegue clicar no `input` que está desabilitado.

Quando vc preenche o obrigatório ele remove o `desabled` do outro `input` no `keyup`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** caso queira estilizar o `input:disabled` basta usar a pseudo classe `:disabled`. Repare que eu tb removi o `tabindex` do primeiro `input` quando ele ja está valido, assim mesmo com teclado ele fica inacessível. No script quando vc clica no documento ele foca no primeiro `input`, mas se esse `input` já for `:valid` se vc clicar no documento ele vai focar no outro `input`, além disso no CSS eu estilizei o `input:valid` para não ter evento de mouse.

```js
$(document).on('click', function () {
 $('#nome').focus();
 if ($('#nome:valid')) {
  $('#pass').focus();
 }
});

$('#nome').keyup(function () {
 if ($(this).val()) {
  $(this).attr("tabindex","-1").siblings('input').prop('disabled', false);
 }
});
```

```css
input:valid {
 pointer-events: none;
 user-select: none;
}
:disabled {
 background:azure;
 border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<input autofocus type="text" id="nome" required autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" id="pass" disabled required>
```

Comment: tua solução funcionou perfeitamente, porém a minha ideia é manter o foco no Input que possui o foco. Se o foco estiver no Input tt, mesmo que eu clique fora do campo, o foco deve permanecer no mesmo Input. O mesmo para o campo register. Tem como fazer?

Comment: Cara isso vai fazer com que em qq lugar que vc clocar no documento foque no TT, mas como vc vai retirar isso depois eu vou ficar te devendo, até pq to saindo aqui e não devo mexer mais no pc hj... `$(document).on('click', function(){
 $('#tt').focus();
});`

Comment: @Seixas tem um detalhe na sua ideia, se só puder focar no segundo input, como que ele vai poder editar o primeiro input se não consegue clicar nele, e como vai poder clicar no submit?

Comment: Hugo,  a ideia é ler um código no primeiro campo, fazer uma chamada ajax, caso tenha sucesso, o foco passa para o segundo campo que irá ler códigos e acumular via ajax também. Uma ideia semelhante a um coletor. Eu sempre inicio pelo básico, tentei manter o foco no campo e não consegui. A navegação entre os campos será feita com base no resultado da chamada ajax. Você teria alguma dica? Obrigado pela sua resposta

Comment: @Seixas deu uma reformilada no script e no CSS, acho que agora está mais de acordo com o que vc perguntou

Comment: Show Hugo, funcionou. Valeu!!!

Comment: @Seixas legal que funcionou como queria, só tenha em mente a usabilidade disso, tente fazer um teste com os usuários para verificar se esse comportamento é adequando mesmo... []´s

Answer (score 2):

Olá, ao que parece você esta usando jQuery, certo? Tente voltar o foco ao input em qualquer clique na tela, utilizando a função `click`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", function(){
        var campoLogin = $("#login");
        var campoSenha = $("#password");

        // Verifica se campo login está focado e se o clique não foi no campo de senha
        if(campoLogin.is(":focus") && $(this).attr("id") != "password"){
            campoLogin.focus();
        }else{
            campoSenha.focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraço!

Comment: Lucas, obrigado pelo seu retorno, mas não funcionou. Entendi a sua solução, porém se o foco estiver no campo login, precisa permanecer no login, caso esteja na senha, deverá permanecer no campo senha.

Comment: Olá, tente novamente com essas atualizações. Espero que atenda ao que você quer fazer! Abraço.

Comment: Lucas , sua solução ficou show. Valeu!!!